# Use a dynamic Logit with already forecasted predictor values

Tags: time-series, logistic-regression, prediction, forecasting, mlogit

I have a lag one dynamic logit model with factorscores as a stanionary time series with monthly observations.

The lag one order model has the best RMSE value. Each higher lag order models (2,3,..) has worser validation values.

I would like forecast now the next additional two month (t+2, t+3).

Is it better to accept and use a model with a higher lag (2, 3,..) and with it too a worser RMSE, or is it more useful to forecast the factor values as a time-series (e.g. ARMA1,2) and insert these predicted values in the good lag one model?

Thank you very much for your opinions.

Best regards.